# Should the same scaling strategy be applied to both the target class and explanatory features?

Tags: regression, classification, predictive-models, data-transformation, scikit-learn

I'm working with a dataset where the dependent variable is continuos (sale price of houses) and there a couple dozen features I'm using to predict the sale price using a linear regression model. These features include binary dummy variables, categorical, and continuous variables - all on different scales.

The dependent variable (sale price) is skewed, so I've instead created a new feature that is `log(salePrice)` so the distribution is centered. My question is, I had planned on using SckiKit-Learn's [StadardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) class on the explanatory features. Does it make sense to use two different preprocessing techniques, or should I simply use the `log` of all the explanatory features like I do with the dependent variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threre is no reason to require that the predictor variables should be transformed in the same way as the $Y$-variable.  Depending on the nature of the variables, such a requirement make not even make sense! Like, as in your case, some of the explanatory variables are dummys---does not make much sense to transform dummys.  Scale differences between the $Y$-variable and predictors are taken care of by the estimation algorithm.

For more information on reasons to transform---or to not transform, see the excelent answers: [Why not log-transform all variables that are not of main interest?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130262/why-not-log-transform-all-variables-that-are-not-of-main-interest)
[Pitfalls to avoid when transforming data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90149/pitfalls-to-avoid-when-transforming-data)

An answer to an almost identical question:  [Analysing log and square-root transformed variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24467/analysing-log-and-square-root-transformed-variables/24501#24501)